# UseJwtBearerAuthentication signing key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, openid-connect, okta

I'm trying to implement the JWT Bearer Authentication in my AspNetCore MVC app (Web API only) using the JwtBearerMiddleware but am getting a `401` response with header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"
```

The relevant code in Startup.cs looks like this:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Authority = "https://example.okta.com",
    Audience = "myClientId"
});
```

With the Authority URL I'd expect the middleware to query my Identity Provider metadata from `https://example.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` to get the `jwks_uri` to then get the signature keys from `https://example.okta.com/oauth2/v1/keys`. I don't think this is happening. What do I need to do to get it to find and use the signature keys? Thanks

Comment: Can you post exception details(enable log and see error logs)?

Comment: @ademcaglin I'm having trouble trying to get to those details as it's all happening in a nuget library. And I can't see anywhere to breakpoint.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After following references and digging into the [AspNet Security repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Security) (specifically the `JwtBearerHandler` and `JwtBearerMiddleware` classes), which led me to the *Microsoft.IdentityModel* namespace which is in an [Azure Extensions repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet) (first the `ConfigurationManager<T>` class, then to the `OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever` class (`GetAsync` method), then to the `JsonWebKeySet.GetSigningKeys()` method), I finally discovered that the *JwtBearerMiddleware* does indeed get the keys from the *jwks_uri* in the metadata. Phew.

So why wasn't it working? What I should've checked earlier is that the ***kid*** in the header of the Bearer JWT did not in fact match either of the *kid*'s from the *jwks_uri*, hence it wasn't found. It was the access_code that I was sending as the bearer token. The id_token on the other hand does have a *kid* that matches, so using that instead it worked!

I've since read:

> The OIDC Access Token is applicable only for the Okta
>   /oauth2/v1/userinfo endpoint and thus should be treated as opaque by
>   the application. The application does not need to validate it since it
>   should not be used against other resource servers. The format of it
>   and the key used to sign it are subject to change without prior
>   notice.
>   [*source*](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc)

...so I can't use the access token.